# Remove Active Class from LinkContainer

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-router-bootstrap

In my react app I have buttons for logging in and out. Logging out isn't a big deal because it's never made active. When using LinkContainer (which is great) it will add an active class of `active` when that route is selected. This is great for everything except `buttons`. When it adds the `active class to my button it adds a padded background color behind the button. I don't want that. Heres the code and image now:

[image: Active class on button]

And here's the code:

```
import { Glyphicon, Nav, NavItem, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { LinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap';

<Nav>
    <LinkContainer to={'/'} exact>
        <NavItem>
            <Glyphicon glyph='home' /> Home
        </NavItem>
    </LinkContainer>
    <LinkContainer to={'/documents'}>
        <NavItem>
            <Glyphicon glyph='education' /> User Documents
        </NavItem>
    </LinkContainer>
    <LinkContainer to={'/login'}>
        <NavItem>
            <Button bsStyle="primary" block>
                <span className='glyphicon glyphicon-log-in'></span>Login
            </Button>
        </NavItem>
    </LinkContainer>
</Nav>
```

I want it to set that active class on everything other than my buttons.

Using `react-bootstrap` and `react-router-bootstrap`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After looking through the code on [react-router-bootstrap](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-router-bootstrap/blob/master/src/LinkContainer.js) and a bunch of different articles and posts I figured it out.

I had to change:

```
<LinkContainer to={'/login'}>
    <NavItem>
        <Button bsStyle="primary" block>
            <span className='glyphicon glyphicon-log-in'></span>Login
        </Button>
    </NavItem>
</LinkContainer>
```

To:

```
    <LinkContainer to={'/login'} activeClassName="">
        <NavItem>
            <Button bsStyle="primary" block>
                <span className='glyphicon glyphicon-log-in'></span>Login
            </Button>
        </NavItem>
    </LinkContainer>
```

Making the `activeClassName=""` worked as it would make sure there was no active class being set.

Extremely helpful for buttons. I hope this saves people time. Here's what it looked like after for comparison:

[image: LinkContainer button with no active class]